# Web Sphere Server basics

Tags: websphere

I am very new to WebSphere Application Server. I need to know the difference between Virtual host and Context root, and the benefits of that context root and virtual host. I have tried to google it also, But I couldn't get the proper information. Hope Stackoverflow will help me to learn.

Answer (score 0):

> **virtual host** - A configuration that enables one host to resemble
>   multiple logical hosts. Each virtual host has a logical name and a
>   list of one or more DNS aliases by which it is known.
>
> **context root** -   The web application root, which is the top-level
>   directory of an application when it is deployed to a web server.

So a virtual host allow you to have different domain names and even certificates configured for the same App server: **www.mydomain.com**/AppName and **www.myNewDomain.com**/AppName

Context root is just the top level directory of an application: www.mydomain.com/**App1** and www.mydomain.com/**App2**